# Daily averages in local time rather than UTC in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to calculate daily averages in local time rather than in UTC for a global sample on Google Earth Engine, but I haven't found a clever way to do this. Does GEE have functions for this?

Here's the code, I'm currently using, which takes daily means, but based on the UTC time stamp that comes with the images:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/74f8b3b27b68578146313aabbf4cb511

```
function meanByDate(imcol){
  // imcol: An image collection
  // returns: An image collection
  var imlist = imcol.toList(imcol.size())

  var unique_dates = imlist.map(function(im){
    return ee.Image(im).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")
  }).distinct()

  var mean_imlist = unique_dates.map(function(d){
    d = ee.Date(d)

    var im = imcol
      .filterDate(d, d.advance(1, "day"))
      .mean()

    return im.set(
        "system:time_start", d.millis(), 
        "system:id", d.format("YYYY-MM-dd"))
  })

  return ee.ImageCollection(mean_imlist)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload the time zones as an asset (maybe [this](http://edu-esriroedu.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/312cebfea2624e108e234220b04460b8_0) one). Filter it down to your area of interest. When you calculate your daily mean, do it separately for each time zone, adjusting the date range based on the time zone. Finally, create a mosaic of the time zone means.

Though I doubt you will see any difference in your means when taking the time zone into account.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-05-20')
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))

var timeZones = ee.FeatureCollection('users/wiell/timeZones')
  .filterBounds(region)

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var dateOffsets = ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1))
var dailyMeans = ee.ImageCollection(
  dateOffsets.map(calculateMean)
)

Map.addLayer(timeZones, null, 'Time zones', true)
Map.addLayer(dailyMeans, null, 'Daily means', false)

var point = ee.Geometry.Point([64.3628, 29.8914])
var value = dailyMeans.mean().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
  geometry: point,
  scale: 1000
})
print(value)

function calculateMean(dateOffset) {
  var date = startDate.advance(dateOffset, 'days')
  return ee.ImageCollection(
      timeZones.map(timeZoneMean)
    )
    .mosaic()
    .set('date', date.format('yyyy-MM-dd'))

  function timeZoneMean(timeZone) {
    var geometry = region.intersection(timeZone.geometry(), 1000)
    var start = date // Convert to local date/time
      .advance(timeZone.getNumber('ZONE'), 'hours') 
    var end = start.advance(1, 'days')
    return ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
      .filterDate(start, end)
      .filterBounds(geometry)
      .select([
        'NO2_column_number_density',
        'absorbing_aerosol_index',
        'cloud_fraction'
      ])
      // .map(function(image) {
      //   return image.updateMask(image.select('cloud_fraction').eq(0))
      // })
      .mean()
      .clip(geometry)
      .set('date', '')
  }
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/50ad9417d4c23acf3680dd74d09e0bd6

Comment: This looks excellent, thank you. I tried to adapt the code to get a FeatureCollection with daily means, but I'm getting "Error in map(ID=0): Date: Parameter 'value' is required."

Also, I was wondering, if I'm picking up the right date now for my final FeatureCollection.

Would you mind having a look again?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/48bf373b8b4fb5cd5efb783df40eec9d

Comment: `finalMeans` fails to calculate because `dailyMeans` images doesn't contain a `system:time_start` property. It already has a formated `date` property.

Comment: Right, thanks. This should do the trick then?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8269efb6f91d18273113c89bba2b2d07

Comment: Sure, but you can simplify it to `var time = image.getString('date')`

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much again, saved my day.

Comment: Another question: I'm trying to map a function over the ImageCollection just after selecting bands, but I'm getting the error "a is not a function".
Would you mind helping again? https://code.earthengine.google.com/51cc843dd019924dd27effaddca2bc16

Comment: I found out this was about the way I created the `filterBadObs` function. When I define the function in a `var` object, it seems it has to appear in the code before it gets called. When I define functions as you did, without putting them into `var` objects, they can be defined anywhere. Is that right?

Here is my updated script, in case it's useful for anybody later: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6589b06f637f839c92372effc6874157